# Stricter narrowing in TypeScript that is only allowed if the narrowed case is possible

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

In the following snippet

```js
interface C1 { kind: 'c1' }
interface C2 { kind: 'c2' }
interface C3<T> { kind: 'c3'; value: T }

function isC3<T, CX extends ([C3<T>] extends [CX] ? { kind: string; } : never)>(
    c: CX
): c is C3<T> /* <------- PROBLEM !!! */ {
    return c.kind === 'c3';
}

// valid use
type C = C1 | C2 | C3<number>;
isC3<number, C>({ kind: 'c3', value: 1 }); // true
isC3<number, C>({ kind: 'c1' });           // false


// invalid use
type D = C1 | C2;
declare var d: D;
isC3<number, D>(d); // D doesn't satisfy constraint never (as expected)
```

I am trying to make the `isC3` typeguard function in such a way that a call to it only compiles if the type of the given type argument has `C3` case in it, otherwise I would like to get a compilation error (please look at the examples)

So everything works, except that I get an error at the typeguard return type:

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'C3<T>' is not assignable to type 'CX'.
    'C3<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'CX', but 'CX' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ kind: string; }'.ts(2677)
```

[image]

Is there a way to get what I am looking for?

Comment: You could always have the type predicate be `c is Extract<CX, C3<T>>` or `c is CX & C3<T>` depending on your use cases.  Does that work or do you need something else? If it works I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: both options worked! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a type `T` that you know is assignable to `U` but the compiler does not know this, and you need to use `T` in a place the compiler expects something assignable to `U`, you can either use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) or possibly `Extract<U, T>`, or you can use the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `T & U`, depending on your use case:

```
declare function isC3<T, CX extends ([C3<T>] extends [CX] ? { kind: string; } : never)>(
    c: CX
): c is Extract<CX, C3<T>> // okay
```

or

```
function isC3<T, CX extends ([C3<T>] extends [CX] ? { kind: string; } : never)>(
    c: CX
): c is CX & C3<T> {
    return c.kind === 'c3';
}
```

Both of these end up resulting in a type which is effectively `C3<T>`.  `Extract<T, U>` filters a union in `T` to just those members assignable to `U` (so if you expect `CX` to be a union, then `Extract<CX, C3<T>>` is reasonable), while `T & U` is more agnostic about unions.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIEZkG9kGtQAmAXMgOQLqnIC+AUKJLIiqgEzZ6EnmtV0PR4SNAGYAPABUAfB3whiZBCNIBuZADc4AGwCuEEhJq1aIOAFsIAZwAOzZAFEAHmCiIw2Wsi-IYOkAjBgAHsQZGBLVHEJABo0AA1kCGcIeUtkAAoAbUjJKQBdROTU5Gy4goB+WS5kSxdQAHM1amQSEAh1aABKKXTPb36EElQ4vq9OkgQwtKcXNzFh2JzpGSxR-uQoCDAdKFCEADo5AmQAXjPFZRU1ujWAeluNbWBjnUsINbAAT2sWU7RMAA+aHYQJyIB0ZgARtApFd+uEwRDoVBFj0cEduEpSLFNLp9MhMNROmp7sgXHo1gjxOCodBUel0dVyJQaMT1uzSfAtG9jHcHqBcc9kK93v0vj9kAARP4YZCg1hw7wECAILRwTaPKDIBSSxVeKliGnI2KSnoENmk6UEIJWECkdyWOCBSwwT7IBAhWquBjINodLXpOBpJI-AIQc3GG6mCw2OwASXA0DeAQ8-V8-kCISmS0WCSSkGKWSW+UKBYIaVKFSq8hIXoaTRavvaXR6awGQxG-XG7qm8WQADJRLlU+yNlsdntDoRTudyJdrsZ+qTBS8eWLvr8Tv85cCd4jaVBYZSItSkXS0GjODWLtjHniSISLQ9yaLvAajefUJeMYoWUS1KO3ictoPKLkB-IgCuwprt44ooNKW6yvKeraiqaoapoWo6ih75niiUpmk+Urajalh2g6TrhK67qerMPp+tAGRBoUoaQBGtDUEAA)